# Why am I unable to edit a layer in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

I imported the Railroad_Crossing_TDA layer from ArcGIS Online into ArcGIS Pro (using the Add Data functionality). However, I was unable to edit this layer (for example, couldn't remove columns). I tried the following workarounds, none of which worked:

1. Duplicate the layer in ArcGIS Online and import the copy into ArcGIS Pro.
2. Make a blank layer in ArcGIS Pro (using "Create Feature Class"), and copy/paste the contents from Railroad_Crossing_TDA layer into the blank layer ("Paste" button was grayed out).
3. Export the table to a CSV file ("Export" button was grayed out).

When I click on the pencil icon in in the "Contents" tab, it shows me a red circle with an exclamation mark next to the layer. When I hover over this red circle, it tells me that "this layer type is not editable". When I right-click the layer and go to Properties->Source, the "Data Type" says "Feature Service Feature Class."

Can somebody  tell me what what kind of workaround I can use for this layer?

Comment: Franck's answer relating to the folder path worked for me. The error that showed up was unrelated to what actually caused the problem. I don't have enough rep to comment under Franck.

Answer (score 1):

Revision to the post:

From ArcGIS Pro: Right-click on the "railcross" layer.  Choose "Data" > "Export Features".

Comment: Doesn't work. It's grayed out :-(

Comment: Let's make sure we are using the same resources.  Are you accessing the feature layer by mark.welsh_fdot9?

Answer (score 1):

You've probably figured this out and moved on by now, but I had this same problem and thought I'd add what I did to this thread in case it can help others in the future.

I tried all of the workarounds you did, along with a couple others that didn't work:

- Selected features and then used "Make Layer From Selected Features" - this output another layer that was also uneditable.
- Using the WFS to Feature Class conversion tool - got errors and it wouldn't run.

What did work was a little silly, but whatever works, right?
I decided to see if I could run another tool that would give me a new output layer. So I ran Clip, and clipped the layer by another layer whose boundaries were larger than this one. The result was a new layer with editing capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are the owner of the hosted feature layer and associated feature service, you may need to enable editing on the hosted feature layer. You can do this from the "settings" tab on the hosted feature layer's page on ArcGIS Online. You can't do this without the correct permissions.

However, it sounds like you want to make an editable copy. One way to do this:

1. Add the data into an ArcGIS Pro map
2. Run the "Copy Features" geoprocessing tool
3. Edit the copy. It's no longer connected to the original feature service

Answer (score 1):

Is the path to the folder very long and complicated? Same thing happened to me, I saved the feature in a shorter folder path. This solved the problem.

Comment: Welcome!In the preferred style of Stackexchange, this kinds of comments are welcome, but preferred as a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is very old already, but I just wanted to share a solution I had. Downloaded a .pitemx file from a .gov site and the feature layers weren't supported for editing. If you use the "copy features" tool and copy the layer, it becomes editable. (at least for me) Hopefully this can help someone!